# why is there a white block on my QTableWidget

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qtstylesheets

I am trying to add dark mode to my app, since I couldn't find anything on styling QTableWidgets I tried to do so from previous knowlage, but it seems that the top area stays the same no matter what do I change, how do I fix this?

[image: QTableWidget]

Here is my QSS:

```
`QTableWidget {
        background-color: rgba(29, 29, 29, 250);
         color: rgba(193, 193, 193, 250);
   gridline-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

QTableWidget::item {
         padding: 4px;
}

QTableWidget::item:selected {
         background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 250);
}

QTableWidget::item:focus {
         background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 250);
         outline: none;
}

QHeaderView::section {
        background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 250);
        color: rgba(193, 193, 193, 250);
        padding: 4px;
        border: none;
}

QHeaderView {
        background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 250);
        color: rgba(193, 193, 193, 250);
        padding: 4px;
        border: none;
}

QHeaderView::section:checked {
        background-color: rgba(70, 70, 70, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing bit is documented [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtableview) (I am talking about `QTableCornerButton`).

Not sure what color you want but this below should be close to what you want to add:

```
 QTableView QTableCornerButton::section {
     background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 250);
 }
```